How to Link Video Credits from Wix CMS to YouTube Playlist Player
I am experiencing issues integrating the YouTube Playlist Player widget with a 'box' element on my Wix site, intended to display video credits stored in a CMS collection titled 'playlist1014FULL_vr1'. Although the first credit appears correctly when the page loads, the credits do not update as the playlist advances to the next video. My goal is for each video's unique credits to display correctly in the 'box' based on the video currently playing in the YouTube Playlist Player. I'm looking for guidance on properly implementing this functionality, including the necessary code placement and any potential widget recommendations that might simplify this process.
What I Tried and What I'm Expecting
What I Tried

Embedding YouTube Playlist Player Widget: I added the YouTube Playlist Player widget to my Wix site and embedded it into a div with the id player.

CMS Data Setup: I created a CMS collection titled 'playlist1014FULL_vr1' which contains the IDs of YouTube videos and their corresponding credit information.

Credit Display in 'Box' Element: I set up a 'box' element on the page to display the video credits, using JavaScript to pull data from the CMS based on the currently playing video ID.

JavaScript Implementation: I wrote and embedded JavaScript code intended to fetch the video ID from the YouTube Playlist Player and match it with the corresponding credit data in the CMS, updating the 'box' element dynamically as the playlist advances.


What I Expected

Dynamic Credit Updates: I expected that as the playlist progresses from one video to the next, the 'box' element would automatically update to show the correct credits for the video currently playing.

Smooth Transitions: The credits would display with smooth fade-in and fade-out effects at specified times (e.g., 10 seconds after the video starts and 30 seconds before it ends).


What Actually Happened

Initial Credit Display: When the page loads, the first video's credits are displayed correctly in the 'box' element.

Lack of Updates: As the playlist progresses to the next video, the credits in the 'box' do not update to reflect the new video. Instead, they remain fixed, showing the credits for the first video.

Style Issues: Additionally, I encountered issues with the styling of the credits, such as background colors and text alignment, which did not appear as intended.


I need guidance on correctly implementing this functionality, ensuring that the 'box' updates dynamically with each video change in the YouTube Playlist Player, and any potential widget recommendations that could simplify this process. Specifically, I'm looking for insights on:

Properly linking the YouTube Playlist Player with the CMS data.

Ensuring smooth transitions and updates of the credit information.

Correct placement of JavaScript code within the Wix environment to achieve the desired outcome.


